# IIS HTTPERR Request_Cancelled errors for ASP.Net Web API application

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

Got a bit of a weird issue occurring with an ASP.NET Web API (.Net Framework 4.8) application running on IIS 8.5.

The application will run responding to requests in < 1 sec and will suddenly spike to > 1 sec.
At the same time a large number of requests appear in the HTTPERR log with the error `Request_Cancelled`.

Failed request tracing shows the request is hitting 1 second in `AspNetHttpHandlerEnter`. This would lead me to think that the application itself is performing poorly, however, monitoring doesn't show any performance issues elsewhere.

Eventually these cancelled requests cause the DB connection pool to run out of connections.

Is there any way to get more info about what might be causing the Request_Cancelled errors in a Web API application?

Comment: "At the same time a large number of requests" and "the DB connection pool to run out of connections" are red flags that somebody might be attacking your server then (like DDOS). You need upfront protection like a good firewall, not changes on IIS/ASP.NET.

Comment: There's no noticable uptick in request throughput. By "large number of requests" I meant a large proportion of the requests going to the server. Sorry should have been clearer!

Comment: @StephenLocke did you figure this out?